# How to close Internal Frames?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I had placed several internal frames in a desktop pane namely

```
JInternalFrame frameint1 = new JInternalFrame("Question 1", true,true, true, true);
```

I was able to maximize and minimize but I was not able to close the internal frame.  Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call setClosed(), as specified in the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setClosed%28boolean%29):

```
jinternalFrame.setClosed(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

But remember that for the jInternalFrame.setclosed(true); you must surround this in a try-catch. This will normally be suggested if you are using an IDE

```
try {
      jInternalFrame.setClosed(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        System.err.println("Closing Exception");
    }
```

hope this helps